# cassandra unable to create thrift socket

Tags: cassandra, rpc

I do not know why i am not able to enable thrift protocol on cassandra.

in `cassandra.yaml` `rpc_start=true` `port=9160`.

OS centos 7

iptables not running

firewalld not running

cassandra ver 3.7 (datastax repo) up and running.

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

JAN installed

JMX enabled

etc..

everything in cassandra configuration is ok, except swap file needed due to lack of RAM.

selinux doesn't matter but permissive.

i am able to connect from remote, but this is the output from `nodetools enablethrift`

```
error: Could not create ServerSocket on address /10.10.30.11:9160.
-- StackTrace --
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address /10.10.30.11:9160.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingServerSocket.<init>(TNonblockingServerSocket.java:96)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingServerSocket.<init>(TNonblockingServerSocket.java:79)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingServerSocket.<init>(TNonblockingServerSocket.java:75)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TCustomNonblockingServerSocket.<init>(TCustomNonblockingServerSocket.java:39)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.THsHaDisruptorServer$Factory.buildTServer(THsHaDisruptorServer.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TServerCustomFactory.buildTServer(TServerCustomFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer$ThriftServerThread.<init>(ThriftServer.java:131)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer.start(ThriftServer.java:58)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.startRPCServer(StorageService.java:408)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1470)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1311)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1410)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$79(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$98/201325936.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Any idea?**

i am able to "connect" with telnet into the port 9160 too.

`netstat` output:

```
tcp        0      0 10.10.30.11:9160        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4395/java
```

`nodetool statusthrift` => not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a conflict with 
`rpc_server_type: hsha`

when switched to `sync` i ve got first a null point exception and then retried few second later it started thrift.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. Before switching to `sync`, try increasing `rpc_max_threads` and use `hsha` as the `rpc_server_type`